# Full OS Build Number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there  a  way I can get the  full  OS build number using python? I have tried using the platform module.

[image]

```
import platform 
print(platform.version())

>>> 10.0.17763
```

And

```
import sys
print(sys.getwindowsversion())

>>> sys.getwindowsversion(major=10, minor=0, build=17763, platform=2, service_pack='')
```

And this results in  **10.0.17763** (this is the build number in fact) but I'm looking to get the full number including  what's  after the  dot(.)  I want to get  **10.0.17763.1518**

I have looked into the sys, os and platform  modules without success.  can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

That is the Update Build Revision, and the only place I know of that it is stored is the registry. You can retrieve it with the winreg module.

```
import winreg

# Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UBR
a = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion')
t = winreg.QueryValueEx(a, "UBR")[0]
a.Close()

print(t)
```